# What does <ctrl-h> do?

Tags: key-bindings

I was just exploring the control key in vim (to make myself more familiar with vim overall) and I don't quite get what exactly happens when I press <ctrl-h>.

So when I used <ctrl-h> in my (modded) vim, it just goes one to the left, **but**, when I'm at the first column of a line, it will go to the previous line instead. Now this functionality would be immensely useful in scripting.

However when I use an unmodded vim (with `vim -u NONE`), it basically is , i.e. it doesn't do the line changing thing.

`:help ctrl-h` doesn't help me at all, as it talks about netrw, which is nice to know, but I'm interested in the normal mode shortcut.

So my questions are:

1. What settings changed the <ctrl-h> key in my modded vim?
2. Is there something that does the opposite of <ctrl-h>, i.e. it goes to the right and if it's in the last column, it skips to the next line (if there is one)

Comment: FWIW there are certain control characters that map *exactly* to other keys, and console vim can not tell the difference between them `<C-m> == <CR>`, and `<C-h> == <BS>` and `<C-[> == <ESC>` and `<C-j>` is a newline. This means you cannot map to one of these key combos without getting the other one also. Gvim is a little bit better about this, and nvim will hopefully fix it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's usually interpreted as a back space.

> :help ctrl-h doesn't help me at all, as it talks about netrw,

Try `:h CTRL-h`, yes case makes a difference for some reason.

> Is there something that does the opposite of , i.e. it goes to the right and if it's in the last column, it skips to the next line (if there is one)

Yes, try `<Space>` for scripting, or <kbd>Space</kbd> in normal mode.